# new column based on combination of 2 columns in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Input DF

```
col1   col2 ..... coln
 1      1             
 1      2                    
 1 .    3                
 2 .    1             
 2 .    2
```

I am trying to add a new column, which should be

```
1. "max" for all the rows of the combination (col1 , max(col2),...coln)
2. "not_max" otherwise
```

Output DF:

```
 col1 . col2 . new_col ..... coln
  1       1     not_max
  1 .     2 .   not_max
  1       3 .   max
  2 .     1 .   not_max
  2 .     2 .   max
```

I am able do this with creating a new DF using groupBy with this new column and joining back to original DF to combine this. Any suggestions on how to implement this directly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one go using `max` as sql window function and compare the calculated `max` with `col2`:

```
df.selectExpr("*", 
    "case when col2 = max(col2) over (partition by col1)" + 
    "then 'max' else 'not max' end as new_col"
).show
+----+----+----+-------+
|col1|col2|col3|new_col|
+----+----+----+-------+
|   1|   1|   1|not max|
|   1|   2|   2|not max|
|   1|   3|   1|    max|
|   2|   1|   1|not max|
|   2|   2|   3|    max|
+----+----+----+-------+
```